# Login to GitHub before pushing android studio code

Tags: android-studio, github, push

I am working on my android studio codes in kotlin and trying to push them into my GitHub repository. I have watched many videos and all of them show the same steps of downloading the Git and adding VCS and then adding the code and finally committing it, here is the video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhfJTOu3_SE

The issue is, once I click on the push button it asks me to log in to my GitHub Account in order to complete the procedure and once I enter the Github username and password it keeps on loading and never redirects to anything.

I try to create accounts in the JetBrains, bitbucket or any other software that can help me to access the authorization for the GitHub and upload the code but nothing works.
Is there something I am missing? I am unable to detect the issue here.
[image: Github login requirement]

[image: error]

Comment: i suggest to try to do it in the terminal first - github recently changed their policy to not allow username + password logins. They now prefer only ssh based logins

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to [AthulMuralidhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8689681/athulmuralidhar) for the suggestion in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74655286/login-to-github-before-pushing-android-studio-code/74667589#comment131774366_74655286):

> i suggest to try to do it in the terminal first - github recently changed their policy to not allow username + password logins. They now prefer only ssh based logins

I just solved the issue by logging into the github account through android studio settings, looking for github and adding my github account.

It no longer asks for permission and directly commits the code into the repository.